# Sorting and removing duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
1        | A        |       70
2        | A        |       32
3        | A        |        4
4        | B        |       44
5        | B        |       98
6        | B        |       10
```

Column 1 contains the ID number of the row, Column 2 a string (which repeats across other rows), and Column 3 a number. I want to keep one entry per Column 2 string, but also the one with the highest number in Column 3. So the resulting table I am interested to get is:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
1        | A        |       70
5        | B        |       98
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: For example: will the string "A" repeat itself later in the list or all the "A" are grouped together and then followed by "B"s and so on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate (no pun intended) question around here, but it's quicker for me to answer this than to look for it right now.

Sort by column 3, in descending order, then do a remove duplicates targeting column 2. Excel always keeps the top-most row when removing duplicates.

---

And now, here's the duplicate. I had a feeling it was one of my own.

[Remove duplicate entries, keeping latest only](https://superuser.com/q/559466/50086)